# Pre-load adMob interstitial ad in AppDelegate and display the ad in other UIViewController

Tags: swift, admob, appdelegate, preload, interstitial

I am trying to pre-load interstitial ad in AppDelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and then display it in viewWillAppear method of another UIViewController. 
Have searched for few hours now, the answer is either in objective-C which I can't fully understand/convert to Swift or just not working. Kindly help to point me in the right direction.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!
    var gViewController = UIViewController()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FIRApp.configure()

        GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "MY APP ID")

        createAndLoadInterstitial()

        return true
    }


    func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial.load(GADRequest())
        return interstitial
    }

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {

        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self.gViewController)

    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(_ ad: GADInterstitial) {
        interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

}
```

In other UIViewContoller:

```
var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let App = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    App.gViewController = self

    if interstitial.isReady {

        interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)

    } else {

        print("Ad not ready")

    }


}
```

Gives the error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: why you are not loading it in UIViewController?

Comment: because the said UIViewController is just a menu, so the user will probably click on some button very quickly (before the ad is ready).

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate `interstitial` object, one in class `AppDelegate` and another in class `UIViewController`, and only the one in class `AppDelegate` gets initiated, that's why when accessing the `interstitial` in class `UIViewController` it's still `nil`.

If you want to access the variable in `AppDelegate` from `UIViewController`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }
    // Now you can access it
    if appDelegate.interstitial.isReady {
        appDelegate.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
        print("Ad not ready")
    }
}
```